# Converto pandas object in integer using python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a little problem in converting a pandas object into integer. Specifically I use one of the available dataset of lending club about P2P lending, there is a column called 'term' related to the duration of the loan in moths not as integer but as object (e.g. '36 Months'), this column is an object type but I need to convert as integer: I don't want '36 months' but '36' and calculate it as int. I've tried yet the datetime and time library but no one of this can reach out a solution. 
the data are available online here: https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action --> LOAN DATA -->  2012 -2013.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
data = pd.read_csv("C://////LoanStats3b.csv", skiprows= 1, low_memory = False)
```

Then i found out this function:

```
import datetime
import time
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger('parsedatetime')

def makeEpochTime(date_time):
    """
    provides the seconds since epoch give a python datetime object.

    @param date_time: Python datetime object

    @return:
        seconds_since_epoch:: int 
    """
    date_time = date_time.isoformat().split('.')[0].replace('T',' ')
    #'2009-07-04 18:30:47'
    pattern = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    seconds_since_epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time, pattern)))
    return seconds_since_epoch
```

But it doesn't resolve my problem.
What can I do?
I use 3.6.0 python version in Jupyter Notebook
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a regular expression to pull out just the digits:

```
data['term'].astype(str).str.extract(r'([0-9]+)').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

When I do this I get:

```
>>> df['term'].astype(str).str.extract(r'([0-9]+)').fillna(0).astype(int).head()
0    36
1    36
2    36
3    36
4    36
Name: term, dtype: int32
```

I don't know how you're getting all 0s.

Comment: df.term = pd.Series().replace('','T').astype(int)  convert to NaN I tried in this way and in your way but it doesn't convert correctly because the code returns me NaN, bui i want that '36 Months' become 36

Comment: You need a `.fillna(0)` in there. Please see updated answer.

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas this error comes up

Comment: Yes I've just tried your code df['term'].str.extract(r'([0-9]+)').fillna(0).astype(int)  and the error posted above comes up AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas this error

Comment: You have to convert to string first. I guess the edit didn't work. It's there now. It's `data['term'].astype(str).str.extract(r'([0-9]+)').fillna(0).astype(int)`

Comment: I know that probably I'm stressing you, so thank you for the patience (I am a beginner in python maybe I should have written in the post), anyway. The code works, but the values are all 0, do you know why? What kind of problem is it?

Comment: Don't worry I'm not stressed. Can you please edit your question to provide some of your data so I can play with it? Thank you.

Comment: I've done, I added the link where you ca download the dataset and enjoy it!

Comment: Can you make a small dataframe with some relevant values? I am reluctant to follow a link I don't know.

Comment: I can't but you can trust the link because it is bank's site. If you searching for Lending Club data on google you can go for it. Anyway, I try to make a small dataframe even tough I don't know how to attach at the post. You know about that?

Comment: Ok I downloaded the data. I'm not able to reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: FutureWarning: currently extract(expand=None) means expand=False (return Index/Series/DataFrame) but in a future version of pandas this will be changed to expand=True (return DataFrame)
  if __name__ == '__main__': maybe for this, this is a warning. Because the code certainly works, so, i don't know

Comment: [link] (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#changes-to-str-extract) I guess that I should add (r'([0-9]+)' , expand = False), but the problem exists at all. I can find a solution.

Comment: I've done it!! Thank you so much @bernie for your help

Comment: @Dalila: great job!